# How to convert function String.fromCharCode in javascript to function in php

Tags: string, fromcharcode

I have a new question. I have short code js:

```
SenAffet += String.fromCharCode(parseInt(YaRabbim.substr(n, 2), 16));
```

How to convert it to PHP?

Answer (score 1):

Answer is: `$int = intval(substr($link,$n,2),16);
           $SenAffet .= chr($int);;`